# How Can I Change The Color Of Other View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this simple storyboard :

[image]

what it does is very simple... if buttonOne pressed, it will go to UIView *viewTwo. and when Back button on navigation bar pressed, it will go back to ViewController.

now, what I want to play with is when this buttonOne is pressed, I want to add some color as background of viewTwo.

here's my .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewTwo;

- (IBAction)buttonOne;

@end
```

and here's my .m file :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonOne {
    UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:27.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    _viewTwo.backgroundColor = colour;
}
@end
```

there's nothing wrong with that code... build successfully and run on simulator without error, but why the color is not showing on viewTwo?

what did I missed here? thanks.

UPDATE : I added this line :

```
[colour release];
```

but it seems that `release` is not working on my Xcode. it says :

> 'release' is unavailable. not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode.

Comment: Your project use ARC compilation it's not necessary to release objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement prepareForSegue storyBoard delegate methode,
remember to name the segue identifier in storyboard scene

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"You segue name identifier"])
    {
        UIViewController* viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:27.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = colour;
```

you can remove : - (IBAction)buttonOne methode

Comment: why you have this line : UIViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController; ? it show me a warning : unused variable 'viewController'. and when I delete that line, it build successfully, but still it gives me white background on viewTwo.

Comment: Are you sure that paste all code ?? the viewController variable is used second line below..

Comment: I was using your code : viewController.backgroundColor = colour; but it gives me this error message : Property 'backgroundColor' not found on object of type 'UIViewController'

Comment: then I change into this : _viewTwo.backgroundColor = colour; it's not producing error message, but it won't change the colour.